# PHP - DomDocument getElementsByTagName('smth')->item($string);

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using a form to insert data into a XML file. This data comes from an input field, and I don't know how I can do to write it on *goodbye* or *bye* depending on the data of the input field using something like this.

```
$hello = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('b')->item($IdOfBtag);
```

And this is the XML

```
<a>
    <b id="bye">
        <name>john</name>
    </b>
    <b id="goodbye">
        <name>emma</name>
    </b>
</a>
```

Comment: How about http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php ? Just define the ID instead of getting it by tag name. Remember that an ID can only be used once in an HTML document.

Comment: [`item()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) expects an integer parameter, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

[`DomNodeList::item()`](http://php.net/domnodelist.item) takes an integer argument with the index of the item. In your case it would be `0`  for "bye" and `1` for "goodbye".

But you just can use `getElementById()`:

```
$hello = $xdoc->getElementById($IdOfBtag);
```